# why it get different results when I process same data by numpy/matlab respectively

Tags: python, matlab, numpy

I have a maxtrix data which shape is 10201*101,and only contains 0 and 1. the codes below is  same peocession by matlab/python,but it get different result,I don't know why...

```
BOUND        = load('C:\Users\1\Desktop\ct06\result_data116.dat');
BOUND = reshape(BOUND,101,101,101);
BOUND(:,:,[1,101]) = 1;          
BOUND(:,[1,101],:) = 1; 
Boundary = find(BOUND>0);  #matlab > Boubdary ： 808243x1 double 

import numpy as np
BOUND = np.loadtxt(r'C:\Users\1\Desktop\ct06\result_data116.dat').reshape([101,101,101])
BOUND[:,:,[0,100]] = 1 
BOUND[:,[0,100],:] = 1
Boundary = np.where(BOUND>0)
print(Boundary[0].size) #python > 809074
```

I really don't konw why it have a two different Boundary (808243 and 809074)?

I guess that the assignment operation is the reason result to the difference(I put off the assignment part,then them got same results).But I still don't konw why...

Comment: Which one is correct?

Comment: don't know.....

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the **shortest code necessary to reproduce it** in the question itself. See: [mcve].

Comment: sorry for that and thank your advise....I don't konw how to upload my data,is it possible?

Comment: Don't upload your data, just find the smallest part of the file that causes different behavior.   Or artificially generate inputs with `rand` or `randn` (matlab, `np.random.randn` for python).

Answer (score 1):

Matlab uses column major ordering, while python uses row major (read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-_and_column-major_order for more details on what this means).  As an example, in python

```
t = np.eye(3)
t[0,1] = 3
np.reshape(t, (9, 1))
```

results in

```
array([[ 1.],
   [ 3.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 1.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 1.]])
```

While in matlab the same command

```
t = eye(3)
t(1,2) = 3
reshape(t, 9, 1)
```

results in

ans =

```
 1
 0
 0
 3
 1
 0
 0
 0
 1
```

Just because commands have the same name in two different programming languages does not mean they will do the same thing.  Just because two commands claim to do the same thing does not mean the results will not be subtly different.  Always test your code with a simple input before throwing all of your data files at it.

Comment: Thank you very very much, I add the order='F' perameter in numpy.reshape method and then get same result ,thank you again!!!

Answer (score 0):

The likely cause is that Matlab uses column-major order, so when you do

```
BOUND[:,[0,100],:] = 1
```

the behavior is different in Matlab and Python.

Comment: Close, but row/column ordering only affects how the data is laid out on disk.  Indexing behaves the same, it's the reshape operation that changes how the on-disk data is interpreted and gives different results.